# HTML5 structure of site title and page title

Tags: html, seo, structure

Is the structure below correct or is the section tag not needed?

For SEO, assuming the relevant keywords are the page title not the site title, is the structure bellow the best optomisation? Thanks

```
    <header>
        <h1>Site Title</h1>
    </header>

    <section>
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
        <p>Page Content Here</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, put I wouldn't but the entire page in a section. Look here http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/

Comment: Looks like your right. So the other question is how to promote the page title more than the site site for SEO.

Comment: Ive noticed the SEOmoz front page doesn't use a header at all!?!?

Comment: Ok, actually quite a few HTML5 sites dont use the header element but im not sure if this is good practice or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't abuse the usage of section and article tags using them for structure, instead keep using divs.

In html5, when using headings and sections, you must check that each section has its own title. You can use the outliner to see how is the structure.
http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/

According to your case you'll notice that the Site Title has still more relevancy than the Page Title. That's okay. But better use a div for dividing the header from the content.

// Reply 12/03/01

You can try using some weird position absolute to achieve your goal:
First of all, the section must have a heading, if not it will be null.

```
<header>
   <h1 id="position-me-in-section">Page Title h1</h1>
</header>

<div id="content">
    <section>
        <h6 id="position-me-in-header">Site Title h6</h6>
        <p>Page Content Here</p>
    </section> 
</div>
```

Comment: So how can I make the page title have more relevancy than the site title? I guess I could use an hgroup and make the page title h1 and the site title h2. The issue is when I dont want them displayed next to each other on the page. I may have to hide the h1 and later on the page make a non semantic but visual header for the page title. Im concerned ill get penalised for this as im hiding an h1 which is a typical spam technique. http://html5doctor.com/the-hgroup-element/

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this without altering strongly the markup is placing the page title in the header and positioning with absolute to the section section.

Comment: Do you really think this is going to help your google rank?? lol

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. The `<article>` tag links the related content together, you can also have multiple articles on one page etc

```
<header>Site Title</header>

<article>
    <header>Page Title</header>
    <p>Page Content Here</p>
    <footer>Page Footer</footer>
</article> 

<footer>Site Footer</footer>
```

Comment: It just indicates that this is a section of content which could exist as a independent item in its own right, not necessarily for syndication.

Comment: Presumably your method would make the page title less relevant than the site title? I want to achieve the opposite.

Comment: The page title will be more relevant to the page content and less relevant to the site in general

Comment: I see your logic semantically, but using an HTML5 outliner tool, the page title is hierarchically under the site title so im pretty sure your wrong.

Comment: It seems to me the mistake your making is thinking the header is the site wide header and so should contain the site's name. Although this may be common practice, in actual fact any section or article can have its own header. As I understand it, putting content within a section or article when their is content outside of it will hierarchically lower the content inside the element. This is the opposite of what I want to do so perhaps I should put my site-wide site's name in a section, and have the page title outside of any section. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on how or if you plan to componetize and/or syndicate your content and then it's however it suites you best.  There are no "issues" with how you have it now other than you only want to use a single "H1" per document. On the flip side - the "H2", "H3" etc can be used multiple times with no negative SEO.

The html5doctor link about section shared is a good resource but also consider these:

http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/

http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/

http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tags/a/when-to-use-section-element.htm